# What is the proper way of passing a recyclerviews position / state between two activities?

Tags: android, scroll, save, position, android-recyclerview

I have two activities with one recyclerview in each, I want to be able to open the second activity and mirror the scroll positions. They both use the same type of LayoutManagers (LIST).

How can I achieve this?

I've tried passing the Parcelable (that you get from calling `getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState()` on the first recyclerview) with the intent and then calling `onRestoreInstanceState` (on the layoutmanager) in the second activity using the same Parcelable but it does not work.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You can just send the recyclerview position to the other activity
Use either the first visble or the last visible position of the recyclerview

```
((LinearLayoutManager)myRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```